# creating an if statement to look for specific button press

Tags: django, if-statement, button, toast

first time poster! I'm still fairly new to coding and Django...

I'm looking to create a django if statement to see if a certain button is pressed. I have a toast set up to show an error warning if a search returns no results, but it also pops up if the user clears the search.

Here's the button(s)

```
<div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="form-control rounded-circle btn form-button ml-2" type="submit">
          <span>
              <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </span>
      </button>
      <button class="form-control rounded-circle btn form-button ml-2 closebutton" type="clear" name="clear">
         <span>
              <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
         </span>
      </button>
 </div>
```

I'd like it to spot if the button with the name/type "clear" is clicked, then it won't run the toast. Toast is below:

```
{% if button == 'clear' %}
<div class="toast custom-toast rounded-0 border-top-0" data-autohide="false">
    <div class="arrow-up arrow-danger"></div>
    <div class="w-100 toast-capper bg-danger"></div>
    <div class="toast-header bg-white text-dark">
        <strong class="mr-auto">Error!</strong>
        <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close text-dark" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
   </div>
   <div class="toast-body bg-white">
      {{ message }}
   </div>
 </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please show the Python code that uses these templates.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like it to spot if the button with the name/type "clear" is clicked, then it won't run the toast.

This `if` statement is only run on the server when it renders the HTML for the web page. It is checking if a variable named `button` has the string value `"clear"`. This has nothing to do with any HTML elements in the page, let alone the name of a particular `<button>`. Instead, the value of the variable `button` comes from the "context" when your Python calls one of the render functions.

> I'm looking to create a django if statement to see if a certain button is pressed.

There are two different ways to handle button clicks:

1. Submit a form to the server which then returns a response with a new page. This can be the same Django template rendered with different values in the context in order to get the behavior that you want.
2. Add an `onclick` handler to the button. This should be a JavaScript function that peforms the action you want. It can manipulate the elements in the page to add a toast or anything else.

The first option is very slow because it will require a new network request. The second option is probably preferred here since it will be very responsive to the user's actions.